# Returning user data from firestore in user service returning null

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the user model from firestore. I subscribe to it and can log the user model within the subscription, but when I try and set the outcome to a variable and use it outside of the subscription it returns null.

```
this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
  switchMap(
    (auth) =>
      (auth)
        ? this.afs.doc(`users/${auth.uid}`).valueChanges()
        : of(null)
  ));

this.user$.subscribe((user) => this.user = user);

console.log(this.user)
```

So as mentioned, console logging user within the subscription does return the current object, but the outer console.log of this.user returns 'undefined'

*EDIT*

I am trying to pass the data from this.user into the following get function:

```
 get userDb() {
    return this.user;
  }
```

which can then be used throughout the application.

Comment: This is because the `console.log` on the last line ran before the data is available.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that `this.user$.subscribe ...` is [asynchronous](https://rowanmanning.com/posts/javascript-for-beginners-async/), therefore, the callback you provided in the subscribe method will be executed AFTER the exection of the console.log statement.

Comment: Okay, so is there a way to get around this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you please provide more context?

Comment: The moment you are setting `this.user` to a value, the value of `userDb()` will be `this.user`, but only if its being evaluated again. This again depends on your context. You can manually tell Angular to re do change detection using the `ChangeDetectorRef`. Does this meet your requirements?

Answer (score 1):

> So as mentioned, console logging user within the subscription does
>   return the current object, but the outer console.log of this.user
>   returns 'undefined'

there's nothing you can do about it, you have to subscribe to the stream and wait for it to returns, that is the nature of an async operation. All your logic that will depend on `this.user` will need to stay inside the callback

```
this.user$.subscribe((user) => {
  this.user = user;
  console.log(this.user);
});
```